# How to store string in stream in Delphi 7 and restore on mobile app in XE6?

Tags: delphi, mobile, delphi-7, delphi-xe6

I develop a server and a mobile client that communicate over *HTTP*. Server is written in Delphi 7 (because it has to be compatible with old code), client is mobile application written in XE6. Server sends to client stream of data that contains strings. A problem is connected to encoding.

On the server I try to pass strings in *UTF8*:

```
//Writes string to stream
procedure TStreamWrap.WriteString(Value: string);
var
  BytesCount: Longint;
  UTF8: string;
begin
  UTF8 := AnsiToUtf8(Value);
  BytesCount := Length(UTF8);

  WriteLongint(BytesCount); //It writes Longint to FStream: TStream

  if BytesCount > 0 then
    FStream.WriteBuffer(UTF8[1], BytesCount);
end;
```

As it's written in Delphi7, Value is a single byte string.

On the client I read string in *UTF8* and encode it to *Unicode*

```
//Reads string from current position of stream
function TStreamWrap.ReadString: string;
var
  BytesCount: Longint;
  UTF8: String;
begin
  BytesCount := ReadLongint;
  if BytesCount = 0 then
    Result := ''
  else
  begin
    SetLength(UTF8, BytesCount);

    FStream.Read(Pointer(UTF8)^, BytesCount);

    Result := UTF8ToUnicodeString(UTF8);
  end;
end;
```

But it doesn't work, when I display the string with `ShowMessage` the letters are wrong. So how to store string in Delphi 7 and restore it in XE6 on the mobile app? Should I add *BOM* at the beginning of data representing the string?

Comment: AFAIK `AnsiToUTF8` returns `RawByteString` but you force an implicit conversion back to `string`

Comment: @Sir Rufo Actually it returns UTF8String. Hm, in the Delphi 7 help is written: UTF8String represents a string in the UTF-8 character set. type UTF8String = type string; UTF8String is the type for strings encoded using UTF-8. UTF-8 is an efficient encoding of Unicode character-strings that recognizes the fact that the majority of text-based communications are in ASCII, and optimizes the encoding of these characters. I changed UTF8: string to UTF8: UTF8String; on the server, but it didn't help/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read your UTF8 encoded string in your mobile application you use a byte array and the `TEncoding` class. Like this:

```
function TStreamWrap.ReadString: string;
var
  ByteCount: Longint;
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  ByteCount := ReadLongint;
  if ByteCount = 0 then
  begin
    Result := '';
    exit;
  end;

  SetLength(Bytes, ByteCount);
  FStream.Read(Pointer(Bytes)^, ByteCount);
  Result := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes);
end;
```

---

This code does what you need in XE6, but of course, this code will not compile in Delphi 7 because it uses `TEncoding`. What's more, your `TStreamWrap.WriteString` implementation does what you want in Delphi 7, but is broken in XE6.

Now it looks like you are using the same code base for both Delphi 7 and Delphi XE6 versions. Which means that you may need to use some conditional compilation to handle the treatment of text which differs between these versions.

Personally I would do this by following the example of `TEncoding`. What you need is a function that converts a native Delphi `string` to a UTF-8 encoded byte array, and a corresponding function in the reverse direction.

So, let's consider the string to bytes function. I cannot remember whether or not Delphi 7 has a `TBytes` type. I suspect not. So let us define it:

```
{$IFNDEF UNICODE} // definitely use a better conditional than this in real code
type
  TBytes = array of Byte;
{$ENDIF}
```

Then we can define our function:

```
function StringToUTF8Bytes(const s: string): TBytes;
{$IFDEF UNICODE}
begin
  Result := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
end;
{$ELSE}
var
  UTF8: UTF8String;
begin
  UTF8 := AnsiToUtf8(s);
  SetLength(Result, Length(UTF8));
  Move(Pointer(UTF8)^, Pointer(Result)^, Length(Result));
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

The function in the opposite direction should be trivial for you to produce.

Once you have the differences in handling of text encoding between the two Delphi versions encapsulated, you can then write conditional free code in the rest of your program. For example, you would code `WriteString` like this:

```
procedure TStreamWrap.WriteString(const Value: string);
var
  UTF8: TBytes;
  ByteCount: Longint;
begin
  UTF8 := StringToUTF8Bytes(Value);
  ByteCount := Length(UTF8);
  WriteLongint(ByteCount);
  if ByteCount > 0 then
    FStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(UTF8)^, ByteCount);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes) - is an answer! Fortunately Mobile app and server doesn't use the same code at very much :) Thanks you again!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
Utf8 : String;
```

Use

```
Utf8 : Utf8String;
```

on client. Then conversion is Automatic.

EDIT: Since the client is on a mobile platform, and Embarcadero has decided to eliminate the 8-bit strings in mobile compilers, the above won't work for this particular case. But in other cases where you have an 8-bit UTF-8 encoded string, the Utf8String can be used to seamlessly convert back and forth between UTF-8 and Unicode strings without the need to use explicit UTF-8 conversion functions. Just use it like

```
UnicodeStringVariable := Utf8StringVariable;
```

or

```
Utf8StringVariable := UnicodeStringVariable;
```

and the compiler will insert the appropriate conversion.

Comment: There is no such type Utf8String, I've got E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Utf8String'. I think it's because of the client is mobile application, not desktop. BTW, how it's possible that there is the function UTF8ToUnicodeString on Mobile that requires param of _RawByteStr type. But there is no type _RawByteStr? I can't declare variable of this type!

Comment: `_RawByteStr` maps to the `RawByteString` type introduced in Delphi 2009. 8bit string types still exist in the mobile compilers, they are simply hidden so user code cannot use them directly anymore, but the RTL internals (especially the `System` unit) still do.

Comment: @tikskit: Ah! The (in)famous 8-bit strings that have been removed from the mobile compiler. There's a patch you can apply to re-introduce them: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2013/10/the-return-of-the-byte-strings/ although this may only be a stop-gap measure.

Comment: @HeartWare thanks for the link. I'm going to apply this patch http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2014/05/ide-fix-pack-5-6-for-xe6-released/ hoping it includes this fixes as well